# Hide credential providers in C++

Tags: group-policy

The credential provider can be hide in windows, setting the disable key to true.How to hide the credential provider in windows without having to disable their key in system registry?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able change some Group Policy settings, dependant on t he credential provider you are using, with the [C++ Group Policy API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_policy/). A few vendors have Group Policy keys that you can edit, which avoids editing the system registry programmatically.

Comment: My operating system is Windows 10. Hiding credential providers via group policy only work in windows 7 Professional and Ultimate and Windows 8 Professional and Ultimate.